# Nginx on docker - Vary: Accept-Encoding header is missing

Tags: angular, http, docker, nginx, single-page-application

I'm serving a static website from nginx that runs on a *docker* container which is based on *nginx:alpine* base image.

My DockerFile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=angular-built app/dist/dayTwoApp /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

The default.conf file:

```
server {
   listen 80;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_types    text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I see the vary : Accept-Encoding header in the response from a served html file (see below).

**But for some reason i don't see the header in the js and css responses.**

(*) Relevant references which didn't work:

- [enable gzip compression with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999606/enable-gzip-compression-with-nginx)
- [Set Vary: Accept-Encoding Header (nginx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637678/set-vary-accept-encoding-header-nginx)

**Details of responses:**

html file:
[image]

js files (also for css):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding to your nginx configuration:

```
gzip_proxied any
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    image/svg+xml;
```

(Only responses with the “text/html” type are [always compressed](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_vary).)

Answer (score 1):

In your second example Nginx is returning HTTP response code 304 which indicates the content has not been modified from your cached copy. In accordance with the HTTP specification:

> The 304 response MUST NOT contain a message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.
>
> The response MUST include the following header fields:
>
> ```
>   - Date, unless its omission is required by section 14.18.1
>   - ETag and/or Content-Location, if the header would have been sent
>     in a 200 response to the same request
>   - Expires, Cache-Control, and/or Vary, if the field-value might
>     differ from that sent in any previous response for the same
>     variant
> ```

So if the original cached response already contained the Vary header then it's quite correct that this 304 response would not.